# Solve $(x-2)\ln x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How to solve:

$(x-2)\ln x=0$

It seems pretty easy, but I just can't figure out how to solve this. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like you would solve $(x-2)(x+3)=0$. Set each piece equal to $0$ and solve. So where is $x-2=0$ and where is $\ln x = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

A multiplication is zero iff one of the multiplicands is zero.
$$(x-2)\ln x=0\\
 \longleftrightarrow x-2=0 \text{ or } \ln x=0
\\ \longleftrightarrow x=2 \text{ or } x=1$$
So the solutions are $x=2$ and $x=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{If }\textit{ab}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\textit{a = 0}\quad or\quad b = 0$$
$$(\text{You should know this in elementary school})$$

$$(x-2)\ln{x}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\text{(x - 2)}=0\quad or\quad \ln{x}=0$$